# number of addresses in JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have the following JSON (which I validated and verified is correct) and I'm trying to get the number of addresses.
When I do a

> `var location = req.body;`

I get

```
{ AddressValidateRequest:
   { '-USERID': 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
     Address: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] } }
```

How do I get the number of addresses?

```
{
    "AddressValidateRequest": {
        "-USERID": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "Address": [
            {
                "-ID": "0",
                "FirmName": "firmname",
                "Address1": "address1here",
                "Address2": "13 infinite loop",
                "City": "new york",
                "State": "NY",
                "Zip5": "zip5here",
                "Zip4": "zip4here"
            },
            {
                "-ID": "1",
                "FirmName": "firmhere",
                "Address1": "address1here",
                "Address2": "1 Smith Ct ",
                "City": "San Predo",
                "State": "CA",
                "Zip5": "ziphere",
                "Zip4": "ziphere1"
            },
            {
                "-ID": "1",
                "FirmName": "firmhere",
                "Address1": "address1here",
                "Address2": "12 John Rd ",
                "City": "Newark",
                "State": "PA",
                "Zip5": "ziphere",
                "Zip4": "ziphere1"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it

```
req.body.AddressValidateRequest.Address.length
```

To get a specific address, (e.g., the first)

```
req.body.AddressValidateRequest.Address[0]
```

To get a field on an address

```
req.body.AddressValidateRequest.Address[0].City
// "New York"
```

Comment: Actually that didn't work, but since I was assigning req.body to location I did 'console.log (location.AddressValidateRequest.Address.length);' and it worked. I tried your suggestions and I got an error: "ReferenceError: request is not defined<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Object.handle"

Comment: Please update your answer to location.AddressValidateRequest.Address.length and I will mark it answered, because you essentially gave me the answer.

Comment: Although req.body.AddressValidateRequest.Address.length did work.

Comment: sorry about that, you can name the local variables whatever you want. I updated the answer to `req`.